# Help deploy django with ember

Tags: django, ember.js

So I have a django project with ember web static pages, so basically i have an api side of the website and the web static pages and i want to deploy everything in a free host for 30 days maybe because of a school project.
I already tried on pythonanywhere but i can only deploy the api part.
Can someone help me or tell me a good place to deploy?
Thanks.

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't deploy the static part to Pythonanywhere as well.

Comment: I putted the api online but know i don't know how to put the web

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- if you have questions on how to serve the static portion from PythonAnywhere, just ask in our forums -- we'll do our best to help you sort it out.